# VBA selecting a value from dropdown box on a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFWt.jpg)[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpltN.jpg)I'm trying to use VBA to log me into a secure webpage, then navigate to a webpage where I need to select a value from a drop down box before searching the database.

I cannot get the last part where it selects the value in the drop down box to work, I have used the below code.

The drop down box Name is = District, text value is "South" and combo value for South is A in HTML code. Can someone please help (read a couple of other posts but didn't understand them).

```
    Sub database()

Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

'add worksheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet


'destination
 Set destsheet = ActiveSheet
'use internet explorer
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
' with internet open, make this visable and go to webpage x, enter username 
and passwork
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("URL")
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
'.Document.getElementsbyname("User name").Focus
.Document.getElementsByName("username")(0).Value = "username"
.Document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "Pword"
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
'log in (submit)
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
           If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
           objCollection(i).Name = "" Then
             ' "Search" button is found
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)

    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
'upon logging in naviage to webpage...
objElement.Click
.Navigate ("URL 2")

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Debug.Print .LocationURL
End With

With IE
IE.doc.getElementsByName("district").Item(A).Selected = True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your html? Please also indicate clearly which drop down selection you are after. Item(A).Selected = True is expecting a variable called A btw.

Comment: So the HTML code for the drop down box objectname is "District" the option value i want to select has the Value "A" which correspondence to the text value "South" - so i want the value to be equal to south.

Comment: apologies pressed enter by accident half way though last message :')

Comment: I couldn't embed but link with to image at top of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.document.querySelector("Select[name=District] option[value=A]").Selected = True
```

The `Select[name=District] option[value=A]` is a CSS selector. It looks for elements with `option` tag with attribute `value` whose value `= A` and with a parent element whose tag is `Select` which has attribute `name` with value `District`. The querySelector method of document applies the selector.

Comment: ah brilliant! thank you that worked! just out of interested i've never used query select before, just that just mean select from list in code terms?

Comment: And once again.